# Display a different cell at a specific index in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to populate an ListView in Xamarin Forms with news items and after every 5 items I want to display an Image.. Any ideas how to create a itemSource to accomplish this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Templates%5CDataTemplateSelector/) and then create specific object and put it on each 6th place.

Comment: Totally agree: https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/